# How to easily maintain auditing triggers when add a new column in Mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers, audit

Now I have created a set of triggers to audit all the changes to the table, includes Insert Delete and Update.

But when I add one new column to the audited table, it requires me to add one more sentence to each trigger accordingly.

Is there any way I can write a foreach loop within my triggers to go through all the columns no matter how many columns is and will be in the table? Thanks for any idea.

And is there any tool that helps us build the auditing tables? 
I am wondering since audit is a very popular use, why not mysql come up with some cmd to help us create the audit functions.

something like:

```
Create Table MyAudit
.... 
Audit All/(col1,col2).
```

Then we can get the audit data accordingly from Audit_MyAudit. That would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea helped me improving [the mysql-audit-project](https://github.com/myonara/mysql-audit). In the wiki there is a discussion on `Alter-Table` which explains that one procedure helps you updating the audit-table and the triggers smoothly with on call to a script generator. Once the output script is executed, your data table and the triggers on it is back in sync with the audit_table. Hope that project can help you and others.